# Tell me to say something and I will speak

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Ask me a question and I will answer.

Tell me to say something and I will *speak*,

I can split things up or double them in size.

No, I'm not living, since I am man made.

Most love me, but others forbid my aid.

Some occupation need to utilize me every day.

Some of me may sound like American music makers, but I am far from that.

I have 10 main components with an additional four.

But, if you upgrade me I may do wrong, soak up the sun, or become part of a tree.

So tell me this, What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you

> <s>Arithmetic</s> A calculator/Abacus

Ask me a question and I will answer.

> An <s>Arithmetic</s> calculator answers basic math questions

Tell me to say something and I will speak,

> You can write many words on a calculator (from comments)

I can split things up or double them in size.

> Split = Divide, double = multiply

No, I'm not living, since I am man made.

> <s>Arithmetic is man made although it is based on logic</s> Calculators are man made

Most love me, but others forbid my aid.

> They are forbidden on some exams, but students love them.

Some occupation need to utilize me every day.

> Some cashiers use calculators everyday, as do many other professions in engineering/science

Some of me may sound like American music makers, but I am far from that.

> Texas Instruments is a popular calculator brand, it sounds like a band from Texas playing instruments (from comments)

I have 10 main components with an additional four.

> 10 digits with "+ - / *"

But, If you upgrade me I may do wrong, soak up the sun, or become part of a tree.

> Upgrade a standard calculator to a scientific one, and you get the functions SIN, TAN, LOG which is something wrong, soaking up the sun, and part of a tree (from comments)

Comment: You guess is incorrect, but you mentioned the correct answer in your post!

Comment: oh i got it. Updating my answer

Comment: That is correct, the only thing is ROT13(V jnf ersreevat gb Grknf vafgehzragf(n cbchyne oenaq) sbe bar pyhr, naq va gur ynfg V jnf ersreevat gb FVA, GNA, naq YBT, juvpu ner shapgvbaf ba n pnyphyngbe. :Q)

Comment: Also the fact that you can do this with it. https://www.wikihow.com/Write-Words-With-a-Calculator

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Google?

Ask me a question and I will answer

> Everyone Google's their questions

Tell me to say something and I will speak,

> Okay, Google voice thing.

I can split things up or double them in size

> I'm not entirely sure about this one. Maybe it's referring to how many items you can view per page?

No, I'm not living, since I am man made.

> Thank you, humanity. This is one of our greatest accomplishments.

Most love me, but others forbid my aid.

> Like on a test, or homework, or at work if your boss is stingy.

Some occupation need to utilize me every day.

> I google stack exchange pretty much everyday, would that count? But seriously, Google is imperative for many jobs, mostly because it's used as a fact checker more than anything else (though I would recommend caution with this, it's not good to get reliant on Google if you have a STEM related job...).

Some of me may sound like American music makers, but I am far from that.

> [Goo Goo Dolls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goo_Goo_Dolls)?

I have 10 main components with an additional four.

> I'm not sure what this is. Maybe it's referring to the number counterpart of Google, a googol.

But, If you upgrade me I may do wrong, soak up the sun, or become part of a tree.

> Again, not really sure on this one.

Comment: Great guess, but incorrect. You are close though :D